how to check entire project without specifying directory/file name in ansible-lint with mega-linter config file
ANSIBLE_LINT enablement in Megalinter configurations is not checking the ansible yaml validations.
enabled the ansible_lint in megalinter configuration file. In output getting like this.

It needs to check the all yaml files inside the directory and subdirectory as well without specifying repository name.
Screenshots
Megalinter config file:

Additional context
Running meglinter as container:

docker run -v $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory):/tmp/lint --env-file
<(env | grep -e SYSTEM_ -e BUILD_ -e TF_ -e AGENT_) -e
SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN=$(System.AccessToken) -e
GIT_AUTHORIZATION_BEARER=$(System.AccessToken) -e
MEGALINTER_CONFIG=terraform-pipeline-template/.mega-linter.yml -e
PROJECT_DIR=Networking -e ANSIBLE_DIRECTORY=. -e
CONSOLE_REPORTER_SECTIONS=true -e OUTPUT_DETAIL=detailed -e
JSON_REPORTER_OUTPUT_DETAIL=detailed -e
JSON_REPORTER_FILE_NAME=mega-linter-report.json -e
AZURE_COMMENT_REPORTER_LINKS_TYPE=builds -e
REPORTERS_MARKDOWN_TYPE=advanced -e
SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_PULLREQUESTID=$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
--name megalinter oxsecurity/megalinter:v7

I have some wrong ANSIBLE format files inside that directory. But it's not giving anything in output.
Need a guidance for to do that
azure pipeline yaml file
trigger:

none

resources:
repositories:
- repository: self 
  type: git

- repository: terraform-pipeline-template
  type: git

  name: IaCMasterData/terraform-pipeline-template

  ref: refs/heads/ansible-lint

jobs:

job: TerraformAndMegalinterExection
displayName: Terraform and Megalinter Execution
condition: succeededOrFailed()
pool:
vmImage: ubuntu-latest
steps:

checkout: self
checkout: terraform-pipeline-template
template: ansible-security-checks.yml@terraform-pipeline-template




Are you using Azure DevOps pipeline? If so, please share your yaml file of the pipeline.

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT i added the yaml file image as (azure pipeline yaml file) in top please check.

@Bhawan please paste code as text, not images.

@RuiJarimba added the code but u can find more detailed in the image.

Please format the code, it is not readable

To check all yaml files, you can refer to the followings.

Repo "newmegaLinter": Stores ansible-security-checks.yml and .mega-linter.yml in main branch.


Use -e MEGALINTER_CONFIG=newmegaLinter/.mega-linter.yml to specify the configuration file in ansible-security-checks.yml.

#ansible-security-checks.yml

steps:
# Pull MegaLinter docker image
- script: docker pull oxsecurity/megalinter:v7
  displayName: Pull MegaLinter

# Run MegaLinter
- script: |
    docker run -v $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory):/tmp/lint \
      --env-file <(env | grep -e SYSTEM_ -e BUILD_ -e TF_ -e AGENT_) \
      -e SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN=$(System.AccessToken) \
      -e GIT_AUTHORIZATION_BEARER=$(System.AccessToken) \
      -e MEGALINTER_CONFIG=newmegaLinter/.mega-linter.yml \
      oxsecurity/megalinter:v7
  displayName: Run MegaLinter

# Upload MegaLinter reports
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  displayName: Upload MegaLinter reports
  inputs:
    targetPath: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/megalinter-reports/"
    artifactName: MegaLinterReport


For .mega-linter.yml, set ENABLE to YAML, set ENABLE_LINTERS to YAML_YAMLLINT. You can use FILTER_REGEX_INCLUDE and FILTER_REGEX_EXCLUDE to lint only a folder or exclude some files from linting.

#.mega-linter.yml

ENABLE: # If you use ENABLE variable, all other languages/formats/tooling formats will be disabled by default
  - YAML
ENABLE_LINTERS: # If you use ENABLE_LINTERS variable, all other linters will be disabled by default
  - YAML_YAMLLINT
VALIDATE_ALL_CODEBASE: true
PRINT_ALL_FILES: true
#FILTER_REGEX_EXCLUDE: '(newmegaLinter/)'
YAML_YAMLLINT_FILTER_REGEX_EXCLUDE: '(templates/\.mega-linter\.yml)'
SHOW_ELAPSED_TIME: true
FLAVOR_SUGGESTIONS: false
EMAIL_REPORTER: false
FILEIO_REPORTER: false
AZURE_COMMENT_REPORTER: true


Repo "...-basic": Stores the yaml file used to create the pipeline.

trigger:
- none

resources:
    repositories:
    - repository: newmegaLinter 
      name: newmegaLinter
      ref: refs/heads/main
      type: git

jobs:
- job: MegalinterExection
  pool: 
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - checkout: newmegaLinter 
  - template: ansible-security-checks.yml@newmegaLinter

Run the pipeline, I can see all the yaml files checked by MegaLinter.

The above method will check all yaml files and need to create a pipeline for each source repo. This may be troublesome if you need to check many repos. You can create a pipeline specifically for MegaLinter and use branch policies to check each repo. See the detailed info from Achieve Code Consistency: MegaLinter Integration in Azure DevOps and see Don's sample repo here. I have tested his solution, it works great.
